# How to choose best disc brake rotor for the price? (2006 Honda Accord)

Tags: brake-rotor

I have a vibration on freeway braking that looks to be coming from a slightly warped front disc brake rotor.

Shopping for replacements, I see that "Brakebest" brand has [three different rotors that fit](https://www.oreillyauto.com/shop/brands/brakebest-select-drum-rotor-hub-759), for a range of prices. I've seen from my research that  the more expensive rotors are usually better matched with ceramic pads, and the cheaper rotors with organic or semi metallic pads - how can I find out which combination of rotor and pad types are most suited to my car?

Comment: Welcome to the site @samsmith. Unfortunately your question is requesting shopping assistance, which is off topic. There's no right or wrong answer, it's about your budget, and it leads to opinion based answers.

Comment: tagging this question as opinion-based as the definition of "best rotor for the price" differs from person to person. Anyways, my suggestion is for you to find a seller that caries oem brake rotors. the rotor will definitely be at spec and is a lot cheaper compared to buying it in a honda dealership

Comment: @GdD  I disagree. It turns out that the more expensive rotors are usually better matched with ceramic pads, and the cheaper rotors with organic or semi metalic. My research indicates there is method to the crazy, but since y'all have shut down this thread, looks like these details will not be discussed on SE.

Comment: @Samsmith, you didn't ask that question, it was "how do I make the right choice?". Asking "How do I match pads with discs" or "What's the mechanical difference between these disks" would definitely be on topic, and one we'd be happy to answer if you'd like to edit.

Comment: @GdD  This thread is the classic "Stack Exchange is a hostile place" issue. Instead of offering a conforming response (e.g. "Well, what you should look for in a more expensive rotor is feature X and Y." The community attacks the question and the questioner.  That has the effect of sending users away from Stack Exchange. E.g. https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/    I am not going to take this further.  It is your problem, as you just sent a wants-to-be-participant away.

Comment: @samsmith - I apologize for any misconceptions, but this is a shopping question, pure and simple. You even state right in your question: "***Shopping** for replacements ...*" I'm not sure how this *isn't* a shopping question. If you'd like to ask a new question or edit this question so it's not about shopping, please feel free to. If you believe there is a bigger issue, please send an email to the Community Moderation team. We welcome everyone, but shopping assistance is not one of those questions we entertain.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  As mentioned, this thread is a great example of hostility to new posters. You don't have to engage in a shopping conversation. You can engage it according to whatever rules you like. But forcing new users to conform to rules and "write the same question a different way" is hostile. I will take my auto  questions elsewhere.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Spent 5 min digging around. I do not see how to contact the community moderation team. Pointers?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @samsmith I've edited the question to better fit with the site's aims, using the extra info you've added in comments. I hope this is ok?

Comment: @samsmith - Please use [the Contact link](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/contact), which you can find in the footer of every Stack page.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of brake components largely depends on the type of use. For most everyday drivers, I'd generally recommend going for OEM specification discs(rotors) and pads - the manufacturers put a lot of research effort into designing everything to match.

If you're a heavy user, however, you might want to think about upgrading - a racing driver, for example, would need a combination that won't fade with frequent, heavy use over short periods, so would likely go for top-end ceramic pads and matching discs. This of course leads to a tradeoff, with those components having a shorter lifespan and higher costs - fine if you're a racing driver, not so good if you're using it for commuting!

Personally I would always avoid the cheapest ones too - brakes and tyres are all you've got to stop you in an emergency, so scrimping on them could easily become a false economy.